# Input parameters using eclipse ide using config file or GUI

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have created a `filename.java`  main class for calling other files in the package. In my main class I am setting certain parameters(a file path) which i am hard coding. I like to give the parameters by user itself for which i have two options,

1. create a config file and give parameters from the config file
2. create a GUI which reads user parameters and set the parameters.

Comment: Both are easily achieveavle. Comes down to what you want. As a user, i would like a GUI though

Comment: Ofcourse, as a user perpective, using GUI that it is easy to read the user entered parameters, check them and set it.

Comment: please provide some link or sample for the required task to do

Comment: 1) *"please provide some link"*  See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). 2) Add @PersonName to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: Thanks buddies i was successful in creating GUI using swing.For that i used netbeans to develop the ui.Now its looking realy looking cool

Comment: @PramodKumarG: If you have found a solution yourself, you should post your solution as an Answer and accept it. Until you do, your question still appears in the Unanswered list.